# Eager loading and method type injection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a route that just shows some form:

```
Route::get('/form/{form}', 'FormController@show');
```

In the `FormController`, thanks to type injection I automagically convert form id (from `{form}`) to `App\Form` object and display it in the view:

```
public function show(Form $form){
    return view('form', compact('form'));
}
```

When I get a `Form` object through Eloquent query builder, I can eager load related elements/models like that:

```
$form = App\Form::where('id', '1497')->with('subform')->get()
```

Is there a way to automatically eager-autoload `$form` object with `subform` related object, or do I need to do it manually like that:

```
public function show($id){
    $form = App\Form::where('id', $id)->with('subform')->get();
    return view('form', compact('form'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To automatically lazy load the subform when it is resolved in a route you can customize your route model binding.  Define the custom resolution in the `boot()` method of `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` like:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('form', function ($id) {
        return App\Form::with('subform')->find($id);;
    });
}
```

This will resolve your route parameter `{form}` to the given form while automatically loading your subform.

Answer (score 1):

You can add relation by using [`load()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) method:

```
public function show(Form $form)
{
    return view('form', ['form' => $form->load('subform')]);
}
```

Comment: yeah, but isn't this solution just beautifying the code? It would still make two separate DB querries, or am I wrong?

Comment: It's not possible to load model with relation without creating two queries anyway. You're using model binding and it's also just 'beautifying the code'. It does absolutely the same job as `$form = Form::where('id', $id)->first();`

Comment: Well, AFAIK, the eager loading is supposed to do that - load model with relation in limited number of queries to avoid N+1 problem

Comment: @Gacek `load()` does the same. The difference is `load()` loads relation for existing model. When you're using model binding, you've already have loaded  parent model.

Comment: No, the documentation page you provided says: `load()` is lazy eager-loading, it loads content after parent model was already loaded. I am aware I load my Form object during model binding, but what I'm asking for is exactly that: is there a way to eager load relation WHILE model binding.

Comment: @Gacek to understand how it works, I'd recommend you to install Laravel Debugbar and see what exact queries Laravel will create in both cases for the request. Maybe looking into `Illuminate\Routing\Router@substituteImplicitBindings` method will also be helpful.